# Edit <track> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video

I'm trying to manipulate my  subtitle element's CSS for a video using Javascript. But I need to know the correct syntax to actually get the track element.So instead of using document.getElementBy..., is there one that allows me to get ::cues/track element and manipulate the track within my javascript?